# Javascript file upload

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

In most browsers, an input type="file" has the following files property:

```
document.getElementById("my-input").files
```

This can be used to detect a file is uploaded, and get the file. However, it looks like the files attribute doesn't exist in IE9.

Added:

In jQuery, you can do...

`$("#my-input").val()` to read the file name.  What about getting the files contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [this plugin](http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload).

Comment: That plugin only partially supports IE9, fancy features are IE10+

Comment: For Sure! This answer is from 2011!!