# File attributes access fail in IE 9 and below

Tags: jquery, file, internet-explorer, input, attributes

I want to access file attributes from an input field after a file is selected. By using following code

```
 var file = $("#photo")[0].files[0];                     
 var fileName = file.name;
 var fileSize = file.size;
```

For IE 10, im able to get data:

```
    [object File] {
    lastModifiedDate : Tue Jul 14 12:52:25 UTC+0800 2009,
    name : "Tulips.jpg",
    size : 620888,
    type : "image/jpeg",
    msClose :  function msClose() {     [native code] } ,
    slice :  function slice() {     [native code] } 
     }
```

But, **fail** to use `$("#photo")[0].files[0];` in IE 9 and below.

"Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference"

Is this because input.files just support HTML5. If yes, have any alternative way for this problem?

Comment: Since accessing files via this API is only supported from IE 10 on, this is not really a surprise.

Comment: so, got any alternative way?

Comment: Try looking the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191792/javascript-file-upload